# Should I add launchscreens to my app?

Tags: android, ios, launch-screen

I'm making app for android and iOS with my team for a company
the app is small
its to get prices and delivery locations and the app has 4 activities/view controllers
So should we add a launch screen to our app? I have heard launch screens are to be used when you want to do some kind of work that is to be hidden from the user and that people find it mildly infuriating to wait for the launch screen to go away.
But launch screens look more professional.
What do you say?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Of course you must add splash screen, because it will be your identity of your application

and the splash screen not always doing some progress in background, just make it like timer to get the splash screen away.

and if the user not like for waiting to long you can reduces the time like 1 sec or 2 sec.

so my conclusion is you must add the splash screen

Comment: "...You must add a splash screen..." This is bad advice. You don't always need or want a splash screen and this has nothing to do with the identity of a developer's app. It completely depends on each use case.

Answer (score -1):

**In Xcode 6 and iOS 8 can use XIB/LaunchScreen.storyboard launch app .**

**like:**
[image]

**second,** make sure  Launch screen interface file base name
(UILaunchStoryboardName) in you Info.plist

**like:**

[image]

**next,** after build UI you can launch look effect .

**like**
[image]